# C++ Make a fuction that takes different data types

Tags: c++

I am wondering if I can create a function like this:

```
void printSomething(whatevertype thingsToPrint)

{
    std::cout << thingsToPrint << std::endl;
}
```

so I can do:

```
printSomething("I can print String");
```

and also:

```
printSomething(9);
```

so it takes both string and int data types as the only arguments.

I am not sure if that is possible.

Thanks.

Comment: search for "templates"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called templates

```
template <typename whatevertype>
void printSomething(const whatevertype& thingsToPrint)    
{
    std::cout << thingsToPrint << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you might want to try running that through a compiler

Comment: he said thing**s** to print, not thing

Comment: that only prints one thing.

Comment: @xaxxon: His desired syntax suggests that's all he wants.

Comment: It works exactly with the examples that are in the question -- trying to answer this with some form of varargs would be out of scope for this question

Comment: Making copies of the input is an unfortunate design choice.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm, but how should I put it into a .h file and a .cpp file? and then include the .h file in the main .cpp file? I tried to put the forward declaration in the .h file as:

Comment: So I put the forward declaration as:

template<typename whatevertype>
void printSomething(whatevertype thingsToPrint);

And then, in the .cpp file:
template<typename whatevertype>
void printSomething(whatevertype thingsToPrint)
{
 std::cout << thingsToPrint << std::endl;
}

in the main cpp file, I included it in:
#include "xxx.h"

int main()
{
 printSomething("haha");
 return 0;
}

I got errors says unresolved external...

Comment: @JTWoodson You might want to take a look at [the cpp FAQ about templates](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl). The linked section explains the problem and the 2 following sections give solutions to it. (the simplest way in my opinion is to define the template functions in the .h file)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
void printSomething(const T& t) 
{
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

This will accept any type of object, but will fail to compile if (std::cout << t) would not compile.

Comment: he said thing**s** to print, not thing

Answer (score -1):

The following code takes any number of things to print and prints them.  It returns cout so you can put an `endl` on the end if you want.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


std::ostream & print_things(){return cout;}

template<class Head, class... Tail>
std::ostream & print_things(Head && head, Tail&&... tail) {
    cout << head;
    print_things(std::forward<Tail>(tail)...);
    return cout;
}

int main()
{
    print_things(5, "hello") << endl;
}
```

live: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/OtRfheFc5T62sskb

Comment: If there's something wrong with the answer, please comment

Comment: My guess for why it was downvoted is that if you read the title *"Make a function that takes different data types"* it is about a datatypes and not about printing -- your answer is too complex and unlikely to answer the OPs question